# Getting events that a certain profile is attending

Tags: events, facebook-fql, profile

Im trying t get some info for some events that certain profile rsvp status is attending but it  retrieves blank. Maybe is something about access tolken or whatever.

This is my current fql

```
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description 
            FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 100003454558689 AND rsvp_status = 'attending') 
            ORDER BY start_time asc
```

But it retrieves blank. How can I fix it?

Comment: Check the Facebook Graph Explorer (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and run a few variations. you use "fql?q=" and then copy in your FQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code is good, you just have to make sure you have the user's rights to get that data. So go to the facebook graph explorer, and pop in your code, but this time change the UID to me(). Why does that work?

- Your access token, granted by the Facebook app, determines what user data you can see on Facebook. The Graph Explorer by default shows you your own data.
- So make sure that you have the right permissions for event data. You can test it by the Acess Token drop down on the Graph explorer.
- Here is a list of permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
- Looks like you need "user_events"

So it might be nothing wrong with FQL, but something in the auth process. Good luck.

Comment: In whatever language you're running fql, you prompt the user for authentication, and when they agree to it, your app will get an access_token. Use that in the FQL query.

Comment: but i need to pull the info from a unique profile. Im not understanding how the code would be. can you write a example?

Comment: You can't get it from a profile without the user's permission, which they accept by going through an authentication flow.